# CHMOD setting to hide directory

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

Just wondering what the most common CHMOD setting used to hide a directory and it's contents inside a public_html folder of a Linux server.  Basically just so the public can't access the files at all.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On directories, to hide the contents, executable permission is what allows people to view the contents of the directory.  So if you want the owner and group to be able to read it, then permission should look like this: `drwxr-x---` (`chmod 750 the_dir`).